# Apply function to each column of a database

Tags: r

I am using a particularly niche function, which require the variable name of the column to be analysed written as an object name. I want to loop this function over a number of columns but I don't know how to parse the column name to an object name for the function to work.

Here is an example:

```
library(caper)
library(ape)

tree = rtree(100)
data = data.frame(taxa = tree$tip.label, 
                  value1 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE),
                  value2 = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE))

for(i in 2:3){
  phylo.d(data = data, phy = tree, 
          names.col = taxa,
          binvar = eval(substitute(colnames(data)[i]))
          )  
}
```

The problem I am having is with the binvar argument. The code I currently have there doesn't work, but this was my best guess. This should return the error:

`Error in phylo.d(data = data, phy = tree, names.col = taxa, binvar = eval(substitute(colnames(data)[i]))) : 'eval(substitute(colnames(data)[i]))' is not a variable in data.`

You can see from the argument above `names.col` how the function is expecting column names to be entered (like an object name). The function then uses `deparse(substitute(binvar))` to extract the column from the dataframe.

Can anyone suggest a solution? (other than re-writing the function).

Comment: This is why you don't write functions with non-standard evaluation rules.  I'm referring to the author of `phylo.d`, not to you.

Comment: if my solution is usable, would you kindly consider upvoting it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to build a string for the ENTIRE function call before passing to `evaluate` . In this case, the iterations of your loop would produce:

```
str="phylo.d(data=data,phy=tree,names.col=taxa,binvar=value1)"
str="phylo.d(data=data,phy=tree,names.col=taxa,binvar=value2)"
```

then use`print(eval(str2expression(str)))` to evaluate each.  I used print because `phylo.d` appears to produce invisible output.

If you want to save the output of the call to `phylo.d`, then build an assignment into the string above, and remove the `print` statement.

If you feel comfortable with the `rlang` package and quasiquotation, you can probably build an even neater solution.

Here's my entire solution:

```
build.expr=function(i) {
   paste("phylo.d(data=data,phy=tree,names.col=taxa,binvar=",
     colnames(data) [i],")",sep='')
}

for (i in 2:3) {
    print( eval(str2expression(build.expr(i))))
}
```

FYI : here is my sessionInfo since you asked.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 19.10

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.3.7.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
 [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1
```

When I type ?str2expression it shows a package of base R.

Comment: apologies for the late reply - I was on holiday. This seems like a good route to take, but unfortunately I can't get your answer to work as I can't find the str2expression function you mention. What package is this from?

Comment: changing the last line of code to print( eval(parse(text=build.expr(i)))) worked for me

Comment: Funny - it seems to be in my base R, but since you got it to work ....

Comment: I'm running R 3.5.3 which is the only discernible difference I can see between our sessions. So I guess that is it? :shrug: 
Although also on Mac (but that would be weird if that was the difference I think)